# доступ к _root из загруженного swf

Tags: flash, actionscript

Добрый день. у меня имеется главный файл Base.swf в _root которого много разных переменных и функций. главный файл загружает мой файл Main.swf и я могу из загруженного файла получить доступ ко всем свойствам _root главного файла. Всё это написано на AS2

```
//main.swf
_root.someFunction();
```

Но если я пытаюсь загрузить в своем файле еще один файл load.swf, то из него получить доступ к _root почему-то не получается.

```
//Main.swf
System.security.allowDomain('*');
this.createEmptyMovieClip('module', 0);
module.loadMovie('http://192.168.10.102/load.swf');

//load.swf
_root.someFunction(); //ничего не получается
```

в файле load.swf переменная _root как будто бы вообще пустая, через неё не получается обратиться ни к одному объекту. хотя в тоже время если обратиться к этой же переменной из файла Main.swf то всё работает.

```
//Main.swf
System.security.allowDomain('*');
this.createEmptyMovieClip('module', 0);
module.loadMovie('http://192.168.10.102/load.swf');
module._root.someFunction(); //так работает
```

объясните пожалуйста почему уровень вложенности так влияет на доступ к _root и как мне все таки получить к ней доступ из файла load.swf ? При этом если загружать load.swf не из сети, а из локальной папки, то доступ к _root из load.swf в таком случае есть.